# dataTable does not show any data

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a dataTable with my own data:
the code is like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="bufferData" >
    <p:column headerText="Info" style="width:140px;" >
        <h:outputText value="Total buffer size" /> 
        <h:outputText value="Entry size" /> 
        <h:outputText value="Number of entries" /> 
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="R-P Buffer" style="width:140px;">
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="P-W Buffer" style="width:140px;">
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
            <h:outputText value="-" /> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

but when I run it I see an empty table.
I want to see my data, how can I ?

Comment: Think of the dataTable as a for loop, no data(value) no loop.

Comment: You wanna show a static data, so you can fill a `List` with your static data and then use `dataTable` in normal way.

Comment: thanks, i though i can use static without a list of object

Comment: Hmm, let me add that maybe what you were looking for was this component: [panelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml), since that one allows you to show static data in a table layout (perhaps datatable it's overkill for your purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the var and value attributes.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
//columns
</p:dataTable>
```

After that, you will need to bind value attribute with your managedbean.

See the doc and example on the [datatable showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml).

Answer (score 1):

You have missed few attributes to mention in `dataTable` tag.

```
<p:dataTable id="bufferData" value="#{managedBean.listOfObjects}" var="value">
    <p:column headerText="Info" style="width:140px;" >
        <h:outputText value="#{value.field1}" />  
        <h:outputText value="#{value.field2}" />  
    </p:column>

     // Columns .......

</p:dataTable>
```